# Installing application on iphone it override on the last application

Tags: iphone, installation

When I am installing new application on iphone, this current application get override on the last application,so we can not maintain the previous application.

Please help to solve this installation problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the app identifier in info.plist you can have a different version on the phone at the same time...

However, do you really want to do that?  Most apps migrate by loading a new version, but then updating the old database or preferences to work with the new version of the application.  Just because your application is replaced does not mean the data the user created is replaced.

Comment: Hi Kendall actually when I am installing new application i.e. with other name that time the old application getting override.
E.g. suppose there is app1(old application) and I want to install new application app2(new application). That time app1 get override by app2. So can you please tell me solution on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Product Name in the build settings, that directly affects the name of the .app bundle. You can have two copies of the same app, as long as theyhave different names - this can be helpful for testing a new version while preserving the old, stable version.

As Kendall says, you probably want to use the same name for newer **released** versions of the same application.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I will checked it out.